# CloudConvert job returning null results on export, all tasks listed as waiting

Tags: node.js, express, cloudconvert

I am trying to use cloud convert to convert a pdf into a docx file. when I do this on the job builder, I can see the file download link once the export task is finished. but in Node when I log the job after completion, all the tasks just say waiting and my export task has null results.  how do i access the download link for the converted file?

my code:

```
router.get(
    '/pdf2',
    catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    

        const base64data =  pdf.toString('base64');
    

        let job = await cloudConvert.jobs.create({
            tasks: {
                'pdf_import': {
                    operation: 'import/base64',
                    file: base64data,
                    filename: 'pdf.pdf'
                },
                'pdf-docx': {
                    operation: 'convert',
                    input_format: 'pdf',
                    output_format: 'docx',
                    engine: 'bcl',
                    input: [ 'pdf_import' ]
                },
                'docx-download': {
                    operation: 'export/url',
                    input: [ 'pdf-docx' ],
                    inline: true,
                    archive_multiple_files: false
                }
            }
        });

    

        const exportTask = job.tasks.filter(
            task => task.operation === 'export/url' && task.status === 'finished'
        )[0];
        const file = exportTask.result.files[0];
        
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./out/' + file.filename);
        
        https.get(file.url, function (response) {
            response.pipe(writeStream);
        });
        
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
            writeStream.on('error', reject);
        });
        
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this by adding

```
jobCompleted = await cloudConvert.jobs.wait(job.id); // Wait for job completion
```

after my job tasks